# Tabs don't open in the background any longer in Safari

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, safari, tabs

Whenever I right click on a link in Safari and click "Open Link In New Tab" it leads me directly to it/ immediatley takes me to the new tab. Before, ever since I got my macbook, whenever I opened a link in a new tab it left it running in the background. It was more convinient for me and it was faster.

PS: And before you ask, yes I have tried fixing the "Tab" setting in Safari Preferences

Comment: Could there be a possibility that your Shift key is pressed in / broken as holding down the Shift key while Control Clicking would take your immediately to that tab

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the Tab preferences in Safari please?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps
1. Open preference in safari
2. Click on tabs.
3. Uncheck the option "when a when a new tab or window opens make it      active".

Hope this will works.